# Elasticsearch date_range field with date histogram

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an eventDate which is of type date_range which represent the start date and end date of a particular event along with i have total cost for that event.
I want to create a query with date_histogram which will fetch the data according to days (which is done). But i am having an issue to create a script which calculate the number of days between the eventDate and divide the totalCost/numberofdays and include it in each event

here is the example of data structure

```
{
          "orderType" : "EPO",
          "items" : [
            {
              "cost" : 40,
              "paid" : 1683728555675,
              "description" : "test"
            }
          ],
          "status" : "Paid",
          "totalCost" : 40,
          "date" : {
            "eventDate" : { # this field is of type date_range
              "gte" : 1683311400000,
              "lt" : 1683484199000
            }
          }
       }
```

This is the query which i am using right now

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "orderType": "EPO"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "status": "Paid"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "by_order": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "date.eventDate",
        "interval": "day",
        "format": "dd-MM",
        "min_doc_count": 1,
        "order": {
          "_key": "asc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "totalCost": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "totalCost"
          }
        },
        "include_source": {
          "top_hits": {
            "_source": {
              "includes": [
                "items.description"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```